# Issue with loading of resource file from jar file

Tags: java, guava

I have an app that has such source code layout:

```
src
 main
  java
   com
    mypackage
     MyClass.java
  resources
    queries
      query.sql
```

in my MyClass I can load resource query.sql with

```
URL url = Resources.getResource("queries/query.sql");
String query = Resources.toString(url, Charset.UTF-8);
```

with Guava library when I run it from my IDE locally.

But when I build jar there is such structure:

```
myjar.jar
  com
    mypackage
      MyClass.class
  queries
    query.sql
```

After deployment to server I have:

IllegalArgumentException: resource queries/query.sql not found.

Is it possible to resolve this issue if I don't want to put sql script to mypackage package keeping it in separate folder?
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try `URL url=MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("queries/query.sql");` or `URL url=Resources.getResource("../../queries/query.sql");`..?

Comment: The proper invocation is:  `MyClass.class.getResource("/queries/query.sql")` (note the leading slash in the string)

Comment: Thanks, @VGR. It works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy of @VGR's comment here:

> The proper invocation is:
>   `MyClass.class.getResource("/queries/query.sql")`